# Why does simple logic crash my arduino code?

Tags: arduino, logic

I have found that my arduino app will crash if I use the following logic:

```
if (boolA && boolB) {
    doSomething();
}
```

In a simple program it will work, but with a sufficiently large project, I find I have to change the above to:

```
if (boolA) {
   if (boolB) {
        doSomething();
   }
}
```

In a number of projects I have tracked the cause to this logic.

Comment: who are you?  The thing to consider is, does the compiler generate short-circuit code for `(b1 && b2)` statement?  IF not then there is probably a problem with `b2` that is avoided in the second example.

Comment: :)  Turns out that the second example above isn't very elegant, as I have to duplicate any else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check memory, you can do so by using [Available Memory](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory).
And here I put those files into a library you can use more easily: [Avalaible Memory Lib](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/moti/tree/moti_v2/lib/Memory)

Although, actual code would be better to try to solve your problem...

Comment: This is an example of an eval which will crash: `if (!client.connected() & (millis() - lastConnectionTime > postingInterval))`

Comment: maybe it's a typo, but you need two `&&`

Answer (score 0):

You many need to use the long hand syntax like,

```
if (boolA==HIGH && boolB ==HIGH) {
    doSomething();
}
```

This may also help: 
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,43588.0.html